# Ctrl and Alt don't work after wake up after sleep. Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, sleep

CTRL and ALT don't work when wake up after sleep. Do you know how to troubleshoot this?

The problem is that I cannot press CTRL+ALT+Delete to log in and I need to use on-screen keyboard to enter.

The most weird is that after some time it's back and working OK. This is only after wake up, so it's not physical issue with keyboard, it's software, but I don't know what to do to troubleshoot and find the cause.

Comment: I thought you could only wake a computer from sleep by pressing the power button?

Comment: ctrl alt delete when computer started already